# Get waited time

Tags: ruby, selenium, webtest

I need to check if a element disappears from the page, and the following code works fine for me:

```
def checkavailabilitycheck
    outtime  = 10
    wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => outtime)

    begin
        wait.until { $browser.find_elements(:css, 'img[src="preloader5.gif"]').size == 7 }
        puts "Check succeeded"
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError
        puts "Check aborted, canceld after " + outtime.to_s + " seconds"
    end
end
```

Now i want to add something like

```
puts "Check succeeded after " + wait.tookWhatEverTime + " seconds"
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in this way:

```
w1 = Time.now
begin
    wait.until { $browser.find_elements(:css, 'img[src="preloader5.gif"]').size == 7 }
    puts "Check succeeded"
rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::TimeOutError
    puts "Check aborted, canceld after " + outtime.to_s + " seconds"
end
w2 = Time.now
puts "Check succeeded after " + (w2 - w1) + " seconds"
```

Comment: you beat me by 25 seconds to post the first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

one way is you can save the current time before entering the wait. And get the time when you come out of the wait.

Difference of the two is the waited time.

following is a pseudo code for the logic

```
timeBeforeEnteringThewait = Time.now
//Code for the wait
// after the wait is finished...
timeAfterThewait = Time.now

elapsedTime = timeAfterThewait - timeBeforeEnteringThewait
```